# Processing parameters passed to SQL activity in AWS data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, aws-data-pipeline

I am working with AWS data pipeline. In this context, I am passing several parameters from pipeline definition to sql file as follows:

```
  s3://reporting/preprocess.sql,-d,RUN_DATE=#{@scheduledStartTime.format('YYYYMMdd')}"
```

My sql file looks like below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE RESULT (
STUDENT_ID            STRING,
REMARKS               STRING,
EXAM_DATE             STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION  's3://result/data/run_date=${previous day of RUN_DATE}';  <----(1)

...
insert into temp
select a.roll_number, remarks
from student a inner join result b
on a.student_id = b.student_id
where exam_date>='<start date of previous month of RUN_DATE>' <---- (2)
and exam_date<='<end date of previous month of RUN_DATE>';<---- (3)
```

Here in the above sql, I am not getting any idea how I will achieve (1) ,(2) and (3) from RUN_DATE.

So if RUN_DATE=20190101, then value in (1) should be "20181231", value in (2) should be "2018-12-01" and (3) should be "2018-12-31" .

Answer (score 0):

You can use HIVE Date functions in your SQL to get your desired result:

1. Previous Day: `date_sub(RUN_DATE,1)`
2. Start date of previous month: `date_add(last_day(add_months(RUN_DATE, -2)),1)`
3. End date of previous month: `last_day(add_months(RUN_DATE, -1))`